# Direct sum of $n$ (infinite) cyclic groups isomorphic to direct sum of $n$ copies of $\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism, direct-sum, free-abelian-group

I'm currently selfstudying some algebra and i am currently covering the various equivalent definitions of *free abelian groups*. However, in order to understand why these definitions are indeed equivalent, this question came up and i havent managed to figure it out on my own. The actual question is:

> Assume I have $n$ infinite cyclic groups $$\langle a_1 \rangle,\langle
>  a_2 \rangle,...,\langle a_n \rangle. $$
>
> Does it hold that $$ \bigoplus_{i=1}^n \langle a_i \rangle \cong
>  \bigoplus_{i}^n \mathbb{Z} \quad (n\ \text{copies of}\ \mathbb{Z})?$$

I know that every infinite cyclic group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$. But I couldn't figure out whether direct sums preserve isomorphisms.

If someone has a recommendation for a good book regarding this topic, I'd also appreciate any recommendation.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried constructing an isomorphism between these two groups?

Comment: Yes, direct sums preserve isomorphisms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

This is because they share a [presentation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_of_a_group):

$$\begin{align} \bigoplus_{i=1}^n\langle a_i\rangle&\cong\langle a_1,\dots , a_n\mid \{[a_j, a_k]\mid j<k\}\rangle \\
&\cong\bigoplus_{i=1}^n \Bbb Z,
\end{align}$$ where $[x,y]=x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$ is the commutator of $x$ and $y$.

---

They're also both free abelian groups of rank $n$.

---

I recommend reading Magnus *et al.*'s *"Combinatorial Group Theory [. . .]"*.

---

Another way to see the isomorphism is to construct one out of the $n$ isomorphisms between the cyclic groups and $\Bbb Z$, like so: if $\varphi_i:\langle a_i\rangle\to\Bbb Z$ is given by $\varphi_i(a_i)=1$, then define

$$\begin{align}
\varphi: \bigoplus_{i=1}^n\langle a_i\rangle &\to \bigoplus_{i=1}^n \Bbb Z,\\
(a_1^{\alpha_1},\dots ,a_n^{\alpha_n})&\mapsto (\alpha_1, \dots , \alpha_n).
\end{align}$$ Then $\varphi$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: beautiful, thank you very much for your detailed response. highly appreciating it.

Comment: You're very welcome, @Zest :)